# Collection selector from text input

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code uses a template helper to return the documents to be displayed as well as a text input with class "filterBy" which I need to use to modify the mongodb selector.

On keyup, it should count the character and apply the typed string like `return myCol.find({myField: myCharacters})`

Should I use a Session.set('myChar', jQuery-get-input) and then apply that to the mongodb selector, or there is a better way? Thanks

```
Template.abc.helpers({
  docs: () => {
    return myCol.find({});
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="filterBy" type="text">

<template name="abc">
  <ul>
    {{#each docs}}
    <li class={{this.class}} data-id={{this.a}}>{{this.b}} {{this.d}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a session variable, you could store the value in a [`ReactiveVar`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html):

```
Template.abc.onCreated(function() {
  this.myChar = new ReactiveVar;
});

Template.abc.events({
  'keyup .filterBy'(event, instance) {
    // Get number of characters…
    instance.myChar.set(numberOfCharacters);
  }
});
```

In the helper, get the value of the `ReactiveVar`:

```
Template.abc.helpers({
  docs() {
    const myChar = Template.instance().myChar.get();
    return myCol.find…
  }
});
```

That way you don't store the state, i.e., number of characters, globally but locally on the template level (which also makes you template more reusable).

*See also:*

- An explanation of when to use `ReactiveVar`, `ReactiveDict`, and `Session`: https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/
- The Meteor Guide on storing state in template instances: https://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#reactive-dict-state